# How can we connect a TCP client to a TCP server outside the local network?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

How can we connect a TCP client to a TCP server outside the local network? 
I have tried public IP instead of local IP but that doesn't work.

Comment: Check firewall settings

Comment: "_a TCP Client to a TCP Server_" TCP doesn't have clients or servers. TCP creates peer connections. Client/server is an application concept about which TCP knows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to a setup where you have a home network containing your computer(s), and a router that has a public IP address. In this case you need to setup port forwarding on your router so that it knows to which device on the local network it should forward remote connections arriving on a particular port (it drops those connections by default).

The way how to configure it depends on your router, but it should be pretty simple. Most routers have a web interface, often accessible on http://192.168.1.1 (or see [those instructions](https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Find_Your_Gateway_IP))